# Linking and displaying data from tables in cake php 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, web-deployment-project

I am trying to display the names from the types table in my jobs/index.ctp

not sure how to echo this, so far I have written this

but it is not working but also not giving any error message

```
class Jobs extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('jobs');
        $this->setDisplayField('title');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Categories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Types', [
            'foreignKey' => 'type_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

```
class Types extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('types');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->hasMany('Jobs', [
            'foreignKey' => 'type_id'
        ]);
    }
```

```
<?php
foreach ($jobs as $jobs):
?>
<li>
    <div class="type"><span style="background:"> <?php echo $jobs['types']['name']; ?> </span></div>
    <div class="description">
        <h5><?php echo $jobs['title']; ?> (<?php echo $jobs['city']; ?> , <?php echo $jobs['postcode']; ?>)</h5>
        <h6><strong>company Name: <?php echo $jobs['company_name']; ?></strong></h6>
        <h6>Date Posted:<span id="list_date"> <?php echo $this->Time->Format($jobs['created'], "d MMMM y") ?> </span></h6>
```

It all works apart from this line `<?php echo $jobs['types']['name'] ;?>`

Comment: Associations look right. What does the code reading and displaying the data look like?

Comment: nothing and also i do not get any error messages

Comment: What does *your PHP code* for reading and displaying the data look like?

Comment: <?php foreach($jobs as $jobs) : ?>

    <li>

    <div class="type">
     <span style="background:">
     <?php echo $jobs['types']['name'] ;?>
     </span>
    </div>

     <div class="description">
     
      <h5><?php echo $jobs ['title'];?> (<?php echo $jobs ['city'];?>, <?php echo $jobs ['postcode'];?>)</h5>
      <h6><strong>company Name: <?php echo $jobs ['company_name'];?></strong></h6>
      <h6>Date Posted:<span id="list_date">
      <?php echo $this->Time->Format($jobs['created'],"d MMMM y") ?>
     </span></h6>

Comment: it all works apart from this line

<?php echo $jobs['types']['name'] ;?>

Comment: @GregSchmidt please note I am new to php and cakephp in general so if I am getting your question wrong i apologise

Comment: Much easier to read code in the question instead of notes, so I've copied it there. You can delete those particular notes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `foreach` loop should be `foreach ($jobs as $job)`. Note the singular `$job` for the variable that tracks each particular job.

Following on that singular note, since Jobs `belongTo` Types, there is only a single type for each job, not multiple. As a result, the value you're looking for is
 `$job['type']['name']` (`$job->type->name` will likely also work). This all assumes that you've correctly used containment when loading the record; hence why I asked for that code to be shown too.

If Jobs had many Types, then you'd have `$job['types']` (or `$job->types`), which would be an array of Type entities that you could iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the associated table data you need 3 things:

1. Association in Table,

   ```
   $this->belongsTo('Types', [
       'foreignKey' => 'type_id',
       'joinType' => 'INNER'
   ]);
   ```
2. In controller (JobsController) specify the  associated table using contain,

   ```
   public function index() {
       $jobs = $this->Jobs->find('all')->contain(['Types']);
       //set jobs variable to make it available in .ctp file 
   }
   ```
3. In Jobs/index.ctp file

   ```
   <?php echo $job['types']['name'] ;?>
   ```